# String syntax error occurring while switching from Windows Python to Linux Python

Tags: python, linux, windows, hpc

I am currently transitioning from running a python script just within a PyCharm anaconda environment to running it on a Linux (ubuntu) SFTP. Within this SFTP I've built the job file with all required packages and all modules seem to be installed properly.

I am having problems with random string syntax errors that did not exist before.

E.g this line

```
regFile = (f'{i}_{df.index[0].strftime("%Y%m%d")}-{df.index[-1].strftime("%Y%m%d")}_Model.gz')
```

Runs perfectly fine with no errors on Windows Python.

But when I run it within this Linux supercomputer, I get a syntax error on most strings, but nothing on the rest of the code.

```
File "./test.py", line 355
    regFile = (f'{i}_{df.index[0].strftime("%Y%m%d")}-{df.index[-1].strftime("%Y%m%d")}_Model.gz')
                                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is this common to experience syntax errors transitioning between Windows and Linux? Any suggestions to fix this line of code to work for both?

Thanks!

Have tried ensuring all modules were downloaded properly in case it was a version issue with Python. Have unsuccessfully attempted switching the line slightly to work for both.

Comment: We see a `^` pointing at the end of the line, do you happen to have some invisible characters at the end of the line ?

Comment: Nope, that's just part of the syntax error pointing up towards the end of the line

Comment: Can you run `od -x test.py` and post result including lines 354-356 ? Or save lines 354-356 in test-tmp.py and do `od -x test-tmp.py` ?